# Please make [storage] and [image-storage] synonyms of [online-storage]

Tags: support, synonym-request

In the context of Web Applications most of the questions that use [storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) are referring to [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage). On the other hand, it doesn't make too much sense to use the first to ask questions related to local storage in this site otherwise the question is about the use of  the offline file handling features of a Web App, in such case, the use of [offline-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline-storage) should be considered.

By the way, some people could vote to make [storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) and [image-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-storage) synonyms of [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/online-storage/synonyms

Comment: I'm not even sure [tag:online-storage] is a good tag. It seems a bit too "meta" to me. But, yes, those others seem like they should be synonyms.

Comment: I feel we're better off removing online-storage

Comment: @pnuts yes, those as well

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no tag [storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage).

The usage guide for [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) (with [cloud-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage) a synonym) is presently:

> Storage of files that are available online, also known as cloud storage. Prefer tag [online-backup] where there is an element of automation involved in the transfer of data.

With 3 followers.

The usage guide for [image-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-storage) is presently:

> Apply to questions about the storage of image files that are available online, also known as cloud storage. Prefer tag [online-storage] where the storage aspect has little or no visual element (such as thumbnails of images) and tag [online-backup] where there is an element of automation involved in the transfer of data and/or retrieval is likely to be infrequent.

With 1 follower.

Usage is relatively low for both (55 and 5 Open Qs for [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) and [image-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-storage) respectively) so whether merged/synonymised or kept distinct would make very little difference in practice now or probably in the medium term, but there is a difference in intended use that though subtle is enough to justify independently retaining both tags (now that they exist).