# In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

## Overview

Yesterday I posted the following question [Please make [storage] and [image-storage] synonyms of [online-storage]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/please-make-storage-and-image-storage-synonyms-of-online-storage). At this time, it received two comments mentioning that [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) is a meta-tag, so I'm wondering if there any tag in Web Applications that is not about a specific web app or web app feature, besides bookmarklets and browsers features which are directly related to web application like Greasemonkey scripts that is not a meta-tag.

At this time it looks to me that most tags in Web Applications site  should use the name of a web application or a prefix to related it to a web application to make it be able to be used alone and make it means the same for different people as it's required by the [tags help article](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) but could be exceptions like *things* that are commonly used by different web apps.

Which are those tags, and why aren't meta-tags in the context of Web Applications SE?

Proposal: Add one answer for each of these tags and explain why it's not a meta-tag.

### Related meta-questions

[Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/lets-clean-up-some-meta-tags)

### Examples of tags that are specific to web applications

[facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)
[gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail)
[google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)
[google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive)
[trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello)
[twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)
[youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube)

### Examples of tags that are specific to a web application feature

#### Gmail

[gmail-filters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-filters)
[gmail-labels](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-labels)
[gmail-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-search)

#### Facebook

[facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups)
[facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages)
[facebook-timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline)

### Examples of tags that are not specific to web application

<s>[api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api)</s>
[album](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/album)
[audio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio)
[collaboration](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collaboration)
[database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database)
[dns](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns)
[domain](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain)
[email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email)
**[export](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export)**
**[formulas](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formulas)**
[hosting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting)
[https](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/https)
**[import](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import)**
[ip-address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-address)
[links](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/links)
[offline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline)
[sharing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
**[search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search)**
[sorting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)
[ssl](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl)
[statistics](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)
[url](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url)
[url-shortening](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-shortening)
[video](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video)
**[website](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website)**

### Examples of tags that could be ok as suggested by ale on their answer

[security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
[rss](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss)
[spam-prevention](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention)

### Examples of tags related to bookmarklets or browsers features that could be directly related to web applications

[bookmarklet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookmarklet)
<s>[bookmarklet-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookmarklet-rec)</s>
[userscripts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/userscripts)

### Examples of tags about *things* that are commonly used in web applications and could not be meta-tags

- [html](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html)
- [html5](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5)
- [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

---

### Examples of tags for web browsers

- [google-chrome](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)
- [firefox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox)
- [safari](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think we can come up with a definitive list. It'd be as hard to come up with a list of tags that *aren't* meta-tags.

I think there are some non-application-specific tags that are okay, even if they could possibly be considered meta-tags.

- [privacy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy)
- [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [spam-prevention](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention)

While these don't have much context without being attached to a particular web app, I think they'll be attractive to people who are interested in such things, and there *are* people who are experts on such topics who could answer a lot of our questions.

That's by no means an exhaustive list, of course.

That's why it seems that we would need to discuss each one individually and come to a consensus. Some, like those I've been posting lately, seem obvious *to me*. But I put them up for discussion because someone may have a different take.

---

Let's look at why we have tags at all: They're to help categorize questions so that they're easier to find. "Easier" for who? For the people who have knowledge and can answer questions. Tags aren't much use to Askers; they probably got here through a Google search. It's for Answerers that we have the tags.

There are too many questions here for anyone to read *every* question that comes through, and this is a pretty low-volume site. So we have tags to help Answerers find questions they can answer. For instance, I know a little bit about Facebook (ugh), many of the Google apps, Dropbox, plus a few more. Questions on those topics I can probably answer, so I have a set of favorite tags (or wildcards) so I can find those questions easily.

So, when we look at the utility of a tag, we should really be asking ourselves: "Is this tag something that someone with knowledge would look for?" Who in the world would come to a site about Web applications looking to answer questions about [subscriptions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subscriptions)? A specific *type* of subscription, perhaps, but then it's far more likely they'll be looking for questions tagged with the app(s) they know about.

Comment: I agree that could not be possible to have in a Q&A thread a definitive list of tags but we could discuss about some of them and perhaps discover interesting things about them and about us :)

Answer (score 1):

## Hacking tags

I'm using "hacking" here to refer to the activity of exploring the limits of web applications and to find, not too easy to figure out how-tos that result in a "hack" or "clever solution"

Below is a list of tags that could be "hacking tools" grouped into four categories, including the number of questions tagged for each one.

Is there one or several missing tags missing?

### Basic tools

- [css](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) : 23
- [html](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) : 74
- [html5](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5) : 32
- [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) : 43

### Intermediate tools

- [bookmarklet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookmarklet) : 22
- [userscripts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/userscripts) : 10
- [formulas](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formulas) : 119

### Advanced tools

- <s>[google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) : 351</s>
- [google-api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-api) : 24
- [twitter-api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api) : 21
- [google-chart-api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chart-api) : 6

### Browser extensions

- <s>[extensions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extensions) : 6</s>
- [browser-addons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-addons) : 10
- [firefox-extensions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox-extensions) : 17
- [google-chrome-extensions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extensions) : 46

### Infrastructure

- [dns](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns) : 31
- [ip-address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-address) : 8

## Related

https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3994/please-make-extensions-a-synonym-of-browser-addons

REMARKS

I strike through [google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) as it's web application, not just a tool.

Comment: [tag:automation]?