# Burninate [math]?

Tags: discussion, tags

**UPDATE** Sterling work by @[ale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale) and there are at present no Qs with this tag, so the issue is 'moot'.

---

Tag [math](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) lacks a Usage guide and has three followers but is currently applied to <strike>12</strike> 3 Open Qs:

<strike>[Google Docs mathematics equations reference numbers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87816/google-docs-mathematics-equations-reference-numbers)</strike>

<strike>[Why is the curve undefined in GeoGebra?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104455/why-is-the-curve-undefined-in-geogebra)</strike>

[Plot vector-valued functions in Wolfram Alpha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/plot-vector-valued-functions-in-wolfram-alpha)

<strike>[Does Wolfram|Alpha support Knuth's up-arrow notation?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107802/does-wolframalpha-support-knuths-up-arrow-notation)</strike>

<strike>[What's the full range of supported Google Docs LaTeX macros?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80124/whats-the-full-range-of-supported-google-docs-latex-macros)</strike>

<strike>[MathJax on Ghost](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98078/mathjax-on-ghost)</strike>

<strike>[Cognito Forms: math & decimal places](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92104/cognito-forms-math-decimal-places)</strike>

[Math cases on Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54099/math-cases-on-google-drive)

<strike>[Problem rendering MathJax with Weebly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88523/problem-rendering-mathjax-with-weebly)</strike>

<strike>[Formula for smart, scale-aware number-formatting in Google Sheets? (e.g. 1,024 → 1k, 1,816,7…](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77974/formula-for-smart-scale-aware-number-formatting-in-google-sheets-e-g-1-024-%e2%86%92)</strike>

[Why does Wolfram Alpha timeout when graphing the following equation?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17785/why-does-wolfram-alpha-timeout-when-graphing-the-following-equation)

<strike>[Using amsthm package in blogger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40417/using-amsthm-package-in-blogger)</strike>

Of these some seem more about formatting than mathematics or have tags that already adequately encompass the topic. [One](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87816/google-docs-mathematics-equations-reference-numbers) perhaps merits the tag [math](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), though if the sole Q it would not be enough to ensure the survival of the tag:

> I am creating a document with multiple equations and I want to reference these equations in later parts of the document. Is there any easy way to do this in Google Docs, preferable automatically?

However in my opinion not much different from layout issues in general.

Regarding Shog9’s criteria for burnination, summarised as:

```
    - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
    - Is it unambiguous?
    - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
    - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
    - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
```

IMO the As are, in order: No, No (but should be), Arguably Yes (eg [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets)), No, No.

There is though another consideration not covered above, other than indirectly via ‘followers’. Is it a topic that has experts? Clearly mathematics has these (eg the SE sites: Mathematica, Mathematics Educators, MathOverflow) but, at least from the Qs so far, I see no indication that it is that expertise which  was being sought.

Would anyone care to speak in its defence in a trial for its life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[math](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) in the context of Web Applications it's a meta-tag as it can't be used without any-other tag.

Related discussion: [In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3986/88163)