# Burninate [finance]?

Tags: discussion, tags

**UPDATE** Sterling work by @[ale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale) and there are at present no *Open* Qs with this tag, so the issue is largely 'moot'.

There is one *Closed* Q that should disappear off WA within a fortnight.

---

Tag [finance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) lacks a Usage guide and has <strike>5</strike> 6 followers but is currently applied to <strike>7</strike> 0 Open question<strike>s</strike>.

Other tags with "finance" in them: [google-finance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-finance) and [personal-finance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-finance) (neither with Usage guides).

Regarding Shog9’s criteria for burnination, summarised as:

```
    - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
    - Is it unambiguous?
    - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
    - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
    - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
```

IMO the As are, in order: No, No, No, No, No.

It is a topic with experts (eg see the SE sites: Personal Finance & Money, Quantitative Finance) but it appears usage has had little connection with either of those.

Would anyone care to speak in its defence in a trial for its life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[finance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) in the context of Web Application it's a meta-tag as it can't be used without any-other tag.

Related discussion: [In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3986/88163)