# Burninate [money]?

Tags: discussion, tags

**UPDATE** Sterling work by @[ale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale) and there are at present no Qs with this tag, so the issue is 'moot'.

---

Tag [money](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) lacks a Usage guide and had 2 followers but is currently applied to ~<strike>5</strike> 0 Open question.

Another tag with "money" in it: [ms-money](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-money) (no Usage guide).

Regarding Shog9’s criteria for burnination, summarised as:

```
    - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
    - Is it unambiguous?
    - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
    - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
    - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
```

IMO the As are, in order: No, No, No, No, No.

In addition to 0 Open there are several Closed at present.

It is a topic with experts (eg see the SE site: Personal Finance & Money) but it appears current usage has little connection with it.

Would anyone care to speak in its defence in a trial for its life?

---

Related to: [Burninate [finance]?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/burninate-finance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some candidates to replace [money](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) could be:

- currency
- monetization

But, do we want these kind of tags? In the context of Web Applications all of them look to be meta-tags.

Related discussion: [In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3986/88163)

Comment: We don't want tags like that, unless someone comes up with a web application with that name.

Answer (score 1):

There are no more questions tagged [money](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) and the tag is gone.