# Please remove the lock on "What's the best invoicing webapp?"

Tags: support, specific-question, historical-lock

[What's the best invoicing webapp?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2298)

For some reason, this received a historical lock way back in 2011. Whether it deserves it or not, [we're trying to burninate `finance`](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4277/354), and the lock prevents anyone from editing.

I don't think this should be locked (it's not all that great compared to other [webapp-rec](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webapp-rec) questions), but can a moderator at least remove that meta-tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've removed the lock.

With only a little over 2,500 views it's not really that historically significant.

I've also removed the tag.