# Vote to delete "What's the best invoicing webapp?"

Tags: discussion, clean-up, specific-question

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2298/88163) has the following close reason:

> closed as not a real question by phwd♦ Feb 28 '11 at 20:19
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this
>   question so that it can be reopened, [visit the help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please
>   [edit the question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/2298/edit).

- It's asking for a web app recommendation (It's off-topic).
- It's primarily opinion based question.
- It's a one line question.
- It has less than 3k views.
- It has many one line answers including an external link.

Related discussions on Meta:

- [Please remove the lock on "What's the best invoicing webapp?"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4388/88163)
- [Why lock Qs that failed to be accepted for migration?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/88163)
- [When should I vote to delete a question on Web Applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4463/88163)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come to your aid.  Happy Holidays :)

Comment: ?? Meaning?͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: @Pacerier I cast a binding vote and removed the question